# How to restart an application if any update occurs?

Tags: java, application-restart

My requirement is to restart an application.

I have a User Interface button. When I click on that, it should stop the current running application and should start the same application.

The language being used is java.

Comment: is the button that restarts the app in the app itself, or in a separate app?

Answer (score 2):

Create a process  that will start new application.invoke `java -jar yourApp.jar` using java and stop the current app.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jigar's solution, you might want to delegate additional parameters to the restarted app, such as VM options, program arguments, or the base dir of your application. You could expand this stub to your needs:

```
private static void restartApplication() throws IOException {
    List<String> arguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
    List<String> fullRestart = new ArrayList<String>();
    fullRestart.add(System.getProperty("java.home")+"/bin/java");
    fullRestart.addAll(arguments);
    fullRestart.add("-cp");
    fullRestart.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    // Assuming that 'Application' contains the main method:
    fullRestart.add(Application.class.getName());
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(fullRestart);
    pb.directory(new File(".").getParentFile());
    System.out.println("Starting app - arguments: " + fullRestart);
    pb.start();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: but don't call this directly within a main-method, even for testing purposes - it will infinitely restart itself...

Answer (score 0):

create batch file myBat.bat

```
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 >NUL // wait for your application to stop 3000 milsec
java -jar yourApp.jar
```

before system.exit(0)

call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myBat.bat); // give proper path
```

Comment: This would execute outside of JVM

Comment: @piyush it has to be , because your jvm is going to execute `System.exit(0)`

Comment: Fair enough, in general i don't like to execute something outside of JVM.

Comment: you dont have a choice, do you?